# Do I need two versions of jQuery in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor project it looks like I've got two versions of jQuery running. My app is using the atmosphere package materialize:materialize and I know that one of its dependencies is jQuery. In my meteor/packages folder it shows version 1.11.10 being used.

But the confusing part is in my External Libraries folder. It also shows a version of jQuery 2.0.0. The only npm package that I have used for my app was when I brought in the babel runtime that was required for Meteor version 1.4.3.2. I had in the past installed Materialize from npm but removed it some time ago. Confused to why that jQuery 2 is there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine, it happens this way because of package dependencies, Meteor depends on what is quite an old version of JQuery, and one of your npm packages depends on 2.0.

It does seem strange, but it isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks. The only npm dependency I have is the babel runtime that I had to install for Meteor 1.4.3. Other than that, no npm deps. Everything is Atmosphere. Is Babel runtime depending on jQuery? I didn't think it would be.

Comment: There will be another (probably npm) package that depends on jquery

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is some of the meteor packages depends on jquery and some of the npm packages does the same so you end up having the lib installed twice. Nothing terrible except that clients would have to  download the same library twice. This is a known bug here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6626. Not sure where is it going though, it's been there for quite long already.